# Call Oracle StoredProcedure with multiple output parameters

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jpa, stored-procedures

I have this special case. I have an Oracle stored-procedure that doesn't receive IN parameters but returns 4 OUT parameters.

My entity class is this ...

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "TABLE_NAME")
    @NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
      @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
        name = "MyPackage.spName",
        procedureName = "MYPACKAGE.SPNAME",
        parameters = {
          @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "PO_VALUE1", type = String.class),
          @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "PO_VALUE2", type = String.class),
          @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "PO_VALUE3", type = String.class),
          @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "PO_VALUE4", type = String.class)
        })
    
    })
    public class Tablename {    
        // omitted properties ...    
    }
```

My Repository class is this ...

```
@Repository
public interface TableNameRepository extends JpaRepository<TableName, Long> {

  @Procedure(name = "MyPackage.spName")
  Map<String, Object> spName();

}
```

And I'm calling the stored procedure like this ...

```
  Map<String, Object> spNameMap = tableNameRepository.spName();
  String value1 = spNameMap.get("PO_VALUE1").toString();
  String value2 = spNameMap.get("PO_VALUE2").toString();
  // more values ...
```

But it throws this exception ...

> Positional parameter [1] is not registered with this procedure call;

```
2021-12-29 18:55:13,630 ERROR [http-nio-3000-exec-1] pe.gob.onpe.wsonpe.service.VersionService: InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Positional parameter [1] is not registered with this procedure call; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Positional parameter [1] is not registered with this procedure call
2021-12-29 18:55:13,633 ERROR [http-nio-3000-exec-1] pe.gob.onpe.wsonpe.service.VersionService: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Positional parameter [1] is not registered with this procedure call; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Positional parameter [1] is not registered with this procedure call
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:235)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy123.spFecha(Unknown Source)
    at pe.gob.onpe.wsonpe.service.VersionService.verificarVersion(VersionService.java:32)
    at pe.gob.onpe.wsonpe.controller.VersionController.userLogin(VersionController.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Positional parameter [1] is not registered with this procedure call
    at org.hibernate.query.procedure.internal.ProcedureParameterMetadata.getQueryParameter(ProcedureParameterMetadata.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getParameterRegistration(ProcedureCallImpl.java:311)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureOutputsImpl.getOutputParameterValue(ProcedureOutputsImpl.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getOutputParameterValue(ProcedureCallImpl.java:656)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StoredProcedureJpaQuery.extractOutputParameterValue(StoredProcedureJpaQuery.java:158)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StoredProcedureJpaQuery.extractOutputValue(StoredProcedureJpaQuery.java:142)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ProcedureExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:335)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    ... 61 more
```

It seems that JPA is trying to map parameters by **order** instead by **name**. This behaviour is weird, since I'm using parameter names with the annotation **@StoredProcedureParameter**

Please internet, help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring boot JPA starter calls `StoredProcedureJpaQuery` class on initialization.
That class contains a property called `useNamedParameters`.

Calling your stored procedure like this ...

```
@Procedure(name = "MyPackage.spName")
Map<String, Object> spName();
```

means that spring JPA will map your IN and OUT parameters by **position**
To avoid this, you have to use the annotation **@Param** in your repository, like this ...

```
@Procedure(name = "MyPackage.spName")
Map<String, Object> spName(@Param("PO_VALUE1") String value1);
```

using the **@Param** annotation will set the `useNamedParameters` property to **true** and Spring JPA will not start looking by **position** instead by **name**. But, I don't have any IN parameters in my query. So I changed the method to **INOUT** like this ...

```
@StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.INOUT, name = "PO_VALUE1", type = String.class)
```

and passing an empty string when I call the repository ...

```
Map<String, Object> spNameMap = tableNameRepository.spName("");
```

That solution works for me, but I'm open to see a better solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really answer your *specific* question about how to do these things with JPA and Spring Data, although maybe, you don't have to?

#### Using JDBC for this, directly

JPA and Spring Data don't really offer too much value on top of JDBC for ordinary stored procedures. It's just a different way to manually configure the bindings. So, in JDBC, you'd write this:

```java
try (CallableStatement s = c.prepareCall(
    "{ call mypackage.spname(?, ?, ?, ?) }"
)) {
    s.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
    s.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
    s.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);
    s.registerOutParameter(4, Types.VARCHAR);
    s.executeUpdate();
    String value1 = s.getString(1);
    String value2 = s.getString(2);
}
```

I can empathise with the idea that once you use Spring Data JPA and JPA in some areas, you want to use it everywhere. But I just want to remind folks that Spring Data just wraps JDBC, and in the case of stored procedure calls (unless the procedure returns a set of entities), it doesn't really simplify anything, it just consolidates the programming model.

#### Using a third party library for stored procedure calls

If using another third party library is an option for you, why not try [jOOQ, which has a code generator](https://blog.jooq.org/the-best-way-to-call-stored-procedures-from-java-with-jooq/) to represent your entire schema, including packages, functions, procedures, UDTs, etc as Java code. With jOOQ, you can just write:

```java
Configuration configuration = // Wrapping your JDBC Connection;
Spname result = Mypackage.spname(configuration);
String value1 = result.getPoValue1();
String value2 = result.getPoValue2();
```

Thanks to code generation, everything is type safe, just like when you use XJC to generate stubs for your WSDL endpoints. When you modify the procedure signature, your Java code stops compiling and you can refactor your call code.

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ.